# Does a person need to see 2 trees to make birkat ha'ilanot is this preferable or is this completely unnecessary and carries with it no benefit?

Tags: blessing, trees, see-sight-vision-blind

Does a person need to see 2 trees to make birkat ha'ilanot is this preferable or is this completely unnecessary and carries with it no benefit?

Comment: Related to http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/6715/birchas-illonos-questions , but I won't mark this a duplicate, since it's a bit more specific, and since this aspect of the other question didn't get answered yet.

Comment: Does a person need to see 2 trees to make birkat ha'ilanot is this preferable or is this completely unnecessary and carries with it no benefit?

Answer (score 3):

[Nitei Gavriel Pesach1 6:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46447&st=&pgnum=69) says in the name of [Avodas Hakodesh 198](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=41866&st=&pgnum=15&hilite=) that it is preferable to make on at least 2 trees, however Halacha requires only 1 tree per [Sheilas Yaakov 2:8](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=22294&st=&pgnum=23&hilite=) and [B'Tzail HaChochmo 6:36](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1810&st=&pgnum=319&hilite=).

I have heard that the reason is, since the Bracha is for Ilanos - which is a Lashon Rabim - therefore there are Poskim that say that it is preferable to say it on a minimum of 2 trees. However there are many stories of Gedolim that have said it on an individual tree, (such as Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Aurbach Zatzal).

Comment: Does that mean it's preferable to say Borei Minei Mezonot on two kinds of cookie?